# Stale data exception, closed cursorwindow

Tags: android, database, android-viewpager, android-cursor

I've got an error that I can't solve.

```
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:118)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:135)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2435)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1891)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:792)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:853)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1717)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2279)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15047)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15047)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15047)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15047)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15047)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15047)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15047)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2181)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1095)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6010)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:799)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:599)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:784)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't work out where its coming from because there is no reference to any of my code. I have a viewpager that displays up to 3 listviews based on a database query. The problem above occurs when I change the data that feeds the viewpager from another activity then drop back to the one that the viewpager is in. In onResume I rerun the queries to the database and rerun the loaders that I'm using to put the actual data in the viewpager pages. This all goes fine, and then it crashes! I don't think its the other activity because the changes to the database actually happen and are saved. Anybody any ideas?

Comment: Post the code that refreshes the cursors (I'm assuming you're using a CursorLoader?) also - what provides the cursors? A ContentProvider?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that google tried to give an answer. they say you have to requery() your cursor in order to eliminate StaleException. But they also say that you shouldn't use requery() anymore (deprecated), but to reopen the cursor... i used requery() and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You are using cursor object somewhere after you called  **cursor.close();** operation.

For example,

```
String query = "SELECT category FROM table_name where id=" +
                        String.valueOf(0);
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

String category_name = cursor.getString(0);
cursor.close();

textView.setText(cursor.getString(0));
```

You can solve it either,
By using curser.close() after setText.
Or using category_name instead of cursor.getString(0) inside setText function.

Comment: Neither `cursor.requery()` works nor does calling `cursor.close()` later works. Android is closing the cursor automatically before I have finished using it. Why? I dont know.